# Automatically send email after saving as PDF

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Need help on adding a script that generates an automated email based on the email address in a cell that changes.

I have created a sales order form that once it is filled out the sales person hits the "create PDF" menu and the script creates PDF, saves it in a different folder and clears the sales order form to be ready for the next Sales order.  I would like to also have the ability for the sales order to automatically generate and send the consumer an email with the PDF as an attachment. I have seen multiple examples of these but most of those are a range of emails.  I need it to focus on a single cell (A16) and the email of the sales person so it shows up in their sent Gmail box.  The cell A16 email address changes every time the sales person runs the script because it clears the form in order to create a new SO which in turn places a different address in cell A16.  In addition the email would need a (subject(F2), to(A11), body..., and sales persons name...)

Two other questions

- how can I have the pdf saved based on the name in cell (A11) instead of the sheet name?
- Is this code clunky?  Its seems slow, which I'm not complaining based on the benefit it provides, but if there is a better way to make it faster that would be awesome.

I am not familiar with writing script and have cannibalized all of this from other places found on the innerwebs but here is what I have so far.

```
function onOpen() {

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('create PDF').addItem('create PDF','createpdf').addToUi()

}

function createpdf() {
// Get active spreadsheet.
var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

// Get active sheet.
var sheets = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets();
var sheetName = sourceSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

// Set the output filename as SheetName.
var pdfName = sheetName;

// Get folder containing spreadsheet to save pdf in.
var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).getParents();
if (parents.hasNext()) {
  var folder = parents.next();
}
else {
  folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
}

// Copy whole spreadsheet.
var destSpreadsheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy 
("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))

// Delete redundant sheets.
var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
    destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
  }
}

var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

// Repace cell values with text (to avoid broken references).
var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet.getMaxRows(),
sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);

// Save to pdf.
var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

// Fetch the email address
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sales Order Form")
.getRange("A1:H54");
var emailAddress = emailRange().getValues();
// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'This is your Alert email!'; // Second column
var subject = 'Your Google Spreadsheet Alert';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);


// Delete the temporary sheet.
DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sales Order Form');
sheet.getRange('A11:E11').clearContent();

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sales Order Form');
sheet.getRange('H47').clearContent();

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sales Order Form');
sheet.getRange('A22:H22').clearContent();

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sales Order Form');
sheet.getRange('C25:D46').clearContent();

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sales Order Form');
sheet.getRange('B18:G19').clearContent();

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sales Order Form');
sheet.getRange('G25:G46').clearContent();

var spreadsheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById("URL").getSheetByName("SO tally counter").getRange('A2').setValue
(SpreadsheetApp.openById("URL").getSheetByName("SO tally counter")
.getRange('A2').getValue() + 1);
```

Comment: I don't understand what should the `message` to contain? Just the one line ("This is your Alert email!") or all lines from second column?

Comment: Yuri,Sorry, that email script was something I found and left in there as an example.  I just assumed I could add whatever stock message I wanted into the same area.  The only other problem is it does not appear that that particular email script is taking the saved PDF and attaching it to an email.  I also was not able to get the email script you provided to work either.  Everything else you provided is great though.

Comment: As far as can tell from the code it looks like some working parts were combined without knowledge how these parts really work. So, it impossible to fix via small changes, it's need to rebuilt. I'd advice you to look at some sites where you can hire a pro coder. I'm sure it won't be too costly, the task is not too complicated ever for a novice.

Answer (score 0):

To set a name you probably could replace the line:

```
var pdfName = sheetName;
```

with

```
var pdfName = sourceSpreadsheet.getRange("A11").getValue();
```

The same way:

```
var emailAddress = sourceSpreadsheet.getRange("A11").getValue(); // == pdfName ???
var subject = sourceSpreadsheet.getRange("F2").getValue();
```

As for the rest...

Probably it makes sense to put 'replace cell values with text (to avoid broken references)' before 'delete redundant sheets.' Since there can be references between the sheets and they can be broken when some of the sheets are deleted.

And I'd replace this:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sales Order Form');
sheet.getRange('A11:E11').clearContent();

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sales Order Form');
sheet.getRange('H47').clearContent();

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sales Order Form');
sheet.getRange('A22:H22').clearContent();

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sales Order Form');
sheet.getRange('C25:D46').clearContent();

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sales Order Form');
sheet.getRange('B18:G19').clearContent();

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sales Order Form');
sheet.getRange('G25:G46').clearContent();

var spreadsheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById("URL").getSheetByName("SO tally counter").getRange('A2').setValue
(SpreadsheetApp.openById("URL").getSheetByName("SO tally counter")
.getRange('A2').getValue() + 1);
```

with this:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sales Order Form');
sheet.getRange('A11:E11').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('H47').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('A22:H22').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('C25:D46').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('B18:G19').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('G25:G46').clearContent();

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("URL").getSheetByName("SO tally counter");
var value = spreadsheet.getRange('A2').getValue;
spreadsheet.getRange('A2').setValue(value + 1);
```

Comment: I wasn't able to use your suggestion on the email script but I was able to find one that works with a few exceptions.  I need an if/then statement for the email script.  I am using getrange that contains the email address but because the form clears every time the script is ran a different one will replace the previous one.  On the off chance someone has not placed an email in the data sheet housing all the information I would like the script to give a warning letting someone know that there is no email and if no email they can end script to add email to data sheet or bypass sending to finish.